# Save ,retrieve and upload data to a remote server---(AngularJs / Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Many thanks for all your tutorials that have greatly helped and helping us in so many ways.
Please, i have problem at hands to solve though i'm a newbie in angular/ionic.

1) I have a form that contains several inputs to collect personal info like names, gender, DOB, Occupation etc. At the bottom of the form i have image tag and a button to display and capture image respectively. I was able to capture and displayed the captured image.

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

> 1) I would like to save all the personal info including the captured
>   image on a local storage. Why? because of bad network.
>
> 2) I would like to retrieve the saved info and image and upload to a
>   remote server.

Please, i would be so grateful if you can illustrate this with a simple and short tutorial as you wish.
Thanks once again.

Comment: You can use Html5 Local Storage concept for local storage(for first option) otherwise, you can save all your from data into any .json file(for saving the data into your local system) and upload that file to display(for retrieving purpose)[for both options)

Comment: Thanks so much. Pls can i also save image data in a json file?

Comment: Yes, you can save images info into .json file based on input type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to consider using Cordova sqlite storage. [Link](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)

To do it,

Install the plugin into your ionic project folder via:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git
```

Get ng-cordova.min.js and add into ur javascript directory, add this following line of code into your index.html.

```
<script src="<your folder>/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
```

Inject into your angular module(app.js) via:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

Create a database via :

```
.controller('YourController', function(....., $cordovaSQLite){

 var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("database.db");
 $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS form (id integer primary key, name text, address text, telephone text)");
```

An Insert Example:

```
 $scope.insert = function(name, text, telephone) {
        var query = "INSERT INTO form (name, text, telephone) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [name, text, telephone]).then(function(res) {
            console.log("success!");
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
```

Your image file is then able to store as a blob and have fun ! (:

Comment: The question is specifically asking for a remote server.... how is this to a remote server?

Comment: Hi mate, this answer was posted 4 years ago and I have forgotten why I didn't answer the 2nd part of the question. The answer above is towards his/her first question. If user needs to send to remote server, he/she can retrieve the blob/base64 and send it via REST to his/her middleware. Hope that clarifies.