# Can we make big application in ionic ? how to proceed this kind of applicaton?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a large application in ionic for ios and android.

Back end is already written in Mysql + nodejs

My application does following

1) Login

2) Fetch All Categories for particular user. ( about 200 categories for each user)

3) Fetch all data associated with that Category.(about 1000 records for each category)

4) Offline Access of data

I found similar app was there like get pocket.com. 
My app will do similar kind of tasks.

Can anybody tell me how to do start for this kind of app. Or is it possible to do this app in ionic.

I am very new in ionic

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Login :

As ionic is based on web technologies, (Angular-JS and Cordova), as long as you communicate to your back-end using http post or get, it will pose no problem.

Link:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

2 & 3) Fetching of datas:

You want wish to make a pre-loader which loads all data before showing it in the screen to improve user experience.

U may wish to look at the example here: http://codetunnel.io/how-to-do-loading-spinners-the-angular-way/

4) Offline Access of Data:

See my previously answered question here: [Save ,retrieve and upload data to a remote server---(AngularJs / Ionic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384715/save-retrieve-and-upload-data-to-a-remote-server-angularjs-ionic/33405639#33405639).

You can store it in a sqlite database.

Comment: How to save large amount of  data in sqllite

Comment: also, Can you please tell me how to handle multiple requests

Comment: You have to consider user phone's memory too if you want to store huge amount of data And to handle multiple request, that would depends on what kind of request you need/want and how your storyboard flows.