# Add marker to google map using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Hybride app using Ionic framework and i just want to know if i can add markers in google map using SQLite. 
If yes! can you give me hint please. 
And thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looking at google map dev:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

```
function initMap() {
var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
```

You can probably replace the lat and lng with your variables.

The variables is then retrieved from your SQLite database based on your query.

If you are using SQLite plugin for ionic, do remember to declare the plugin in your controller. You may want to read my other answers in tutorial for SQLite.

[Save ,retrieve and upload data to a remote server---(AngularJs / Ionic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384715/save-retrieve-and-upload-data-to-a-remote-server-angularjs-ionic/33405639#33405639)